# Angular, Http Error blocks any further requests

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-errorhandler

After an error-response from the server my app does not send any further requests.

I'm sending a request with:

```
getMachineRules(rules: Array<string>): Observable<RulesResults> {
    return this.http.post<RulesResults>('/rules', { nodes: rules })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

My  errorHandler:

```
  handleError(error) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${JSON.stringify(error.error)}`);
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
```

And my pipeline looks like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.rulesChanged
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.settings.getMachineRules(this.currentRules);
        }),
        map(data => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.inputs?.length || 0;
          return data;
        }),
        catchError(e => {
          console.log("Error caught");
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = 0;
          return observableOf({ inputs: [] } as RulesResults);
        })
      ).subscribe(
        data => { return this.updateRules(data); },
      );
  }
```

I can see the "Error caught" message in the console and the method `updateRules()` seems to work properly even in the error case.

However after a 404-Error-Response the `ngAfterViewInit()` method is
not called anymore. The UI steel reacts on interactions.

Comment: what do you mean by "the ngAfterViewInit() method is not called anymore"? like you refresh the browser and it is not called?

Comment: no, i click a button which should trigger ngAfterViewInit(), but the method is not executed

Comment: the Observable's stream is "dead" after going thru the process the first time. calling the `ngAfterViewInit` will not re-trigger the `this.rulesChanged`'s Observable stream to start again, i think (though i do not know what `this.rulesChanged` looks like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an Obsevable is failed there is nothing you could do to make it active again, `catchError` is used to handle errors by returning a **new observable** or throwing an error. `observableOf({ inputs: [] } as RulesResults)` is served as **substitute** in case the main stream fails, meaning your main Observable will **never** emit again.

Consider using `retry` at the end of your pipeline, or optionally have your
`catchError` return the source Observable itself, as demonstrated below:

```
catchError((error, source) => {
 ....
  return source;
})
```

Alternately put the `catchError` operator inside a `switchMap` so that only the inner stream will fail while the the outer (main) stream will remain active, as below:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.rulesChanged
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        this.isLoadingResults = true;
        return this.settings.getMachineRules(this.currentRules).pipe(
          map(data => {
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.resultsLength = data.inputs?.length || 0;
            return data;
          }),
          catchError(e => {
            console.log("Error caught");
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.resultsLength = 0;
            return observableOf({ inputs: [] } as RulesResults);
          })
        )
      })
    ).subscribe(
      data => { return this.updateRules(data); },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the explanation! The 2nd solution worked! The 1st one turns the pipe into an endless loop.